# Javascript : Why Can’t I Read the ‘object.style.left’ & ‘object.style.top’ values?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why Can’t I Read the `object.style.left` & `object.style.top` values ?

I’m trying to dynamically move a button.

I can use javascript to reset the `style.left` & `style.top` values by doing this :

```
document.getElementById(theButton_ID).style.left = "128px";
document.getElementById(theButton_ID).style.top  =  "64px";
```

But my problem is that I need to dynamically reset the ‘style.left’ & ‘style.top’ values, using a scaling factor that needs to be dynamically determined when the web page loads.

To my novice way of thinking this means that I need to :

• Get the `style.left` & `style.top` values

• Multiply them by the scaling factor

• Assign those modified values to `style.left` & `style.top` values.

The problem is that I can’t get the `style.left` & `style.top` values in the 1st place so I can’t modify them, much less write them back.

So obviously, I’m both doing something wrong & I'm not understanding something I should understand.

So what am I doing wrong ?

What is it that I’m missing ?

And Most importantly, how do I get the value of `style.left` & `style.top` so that I can use them to dynamically modify the position of the button ?

Thanks everyone for all your help & suggestions.

Here’s the actual HTML / CSS/ Javascript code …

```
<html>
      <head>

         <title>Button Dynamic Move Test</title>

      <style type="text/css">

        #MoveButton
        {
            position    : absolute;
            left        :  8px;
            top     : 16px;
        }

     </style>

     <script>

//      var X_Index_Move_Factor = 1.25;
//      var Y_Index_Move_Factor = 1.50;

function Move_A_Button (theButton_ID)
{
alert (   "We're in 'Move_A_Button'"
        + "\n"
        + " The Button Id = "
        +   theButton_ID
        );              

var the_Old_Button_X_Offset = document.getElementById(theButtonId).style.left;

var the_Old_Button_Y_Offset = document.getElementById(theButtonId).style.top;

    alert (   "the_Old_Button_X_Offset = "
        + "\n"
        +   the_Old_Button_X_Offset   
        + "the_Old_Button_Y_Offset = "
        + "\n"
        +   the_Old_Button_Y_Offset
        );              
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

     <button type = "button"
       id       = "MoveButton" 
      onclick   = "Move_A_Button ('MoveButton')">
     About Us
    </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: weird HTML code formatting.

Comment: theButtonId != theButton_ID

Comment: and the `<head>` missed `<title>` and `meta charset`; missing `DOCTYPE` as well

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you don't need to support IE6 or IE7 (or FireFox from ~17 versions ago), then the best way to go about getting the internal data is something like this:

```
// inside of your function:

var el = document.getElementById(button_id),
    dimensions = el.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log("old x: " + dimensions.left, "old y: " + dimensions.top);
console.log("new x: " + dimensions.left * scale_X, "new y: " + dimensions.top * scale_Y);
```

Just remember that when you set them, afterward, you have to add the measurement, as well:

```
el.style.top = (dimensions.top * scale_Y) + "px";
el.style.left = (dimensions.left * scale_X) + "px";
```

And that using the `getBoundingClient` function will give you measurements as numbers, but `.style.top` / `.style.left` will give you measurements as strings ("112px") which you then have to pull the numbers out of, and then modify, and then when you add them back, you add the measurement type back on...  ...hooray

Answer (score 1):

`theButton_ID` is the name of an argument

```
function Move_A_Button (theButton_ID)
{
```

When you try to get the style you write

```
document.getElementById(theButtonId).style.left;
```

You forgot a underscore

Comment: Still doesn't work though … But the additional answers could solve it … Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Even with the typos corrected, the element doesn't initially have `top` or `left` styles, since none are set on the element itself.

`element.offsetLeft` and `element.offsetTop` are your best bets as starting points.