# javascript moving a div left and right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this mini game and I want that my "player" named div to move to left and right inside of the "game" div but I'm stuck. Can someone help me? I think my error is inside of the JavaScript file... Also if my "player" div moves, will my "gun" div move with it too?

```js
let modifier = 50;
let player = document.getElementById('player');
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const {
    style
  } = player;
  switch (event.key) {
    case 'ArrowRight':
      style.left = `${parseInt(style.left) - modifier}px`;
      break;
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      style.left = `${parseInt(style.left) + modifier}px`;
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: mediumblue;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  font-size: 48pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: -50px;
}

.game {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  position: center;
  border: 14px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  background-color: black;
}

#player {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 470px;
  left: 400px;
}

#gun {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  top: -20px;
  left: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#bullet {
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkorange;
  width: 8px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 1px;
  animation: shoot 0.7s linear;
}

@keyframes shoot {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -470px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Galaxy Invaders</p>
<div class="game">
  <div id="player">
    <div id="gun">
      <div id="bullet"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="enemy"></div>
</div>
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackOverflow. Have you tried anything to solve the problem? Like `console.log({event})` or `console.log({style})` inside the event listener function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript : Why Can’t I Read the ‘object.style.left’ & ‘object.style.top’ values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431831/javascript-why-can-t-i-read-the-object-style-left-object-style-top-value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getComputedStyle`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```js
let modifier = 50;
let player = document.getElementById('player');

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  switch (event.key) {
    case 'ArrowRight':
      player.style.left = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(player).left) + modifier) + "px";
      break;
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      player.style.left = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(player).left) - modifier) + "px";
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: mediumblue;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  font-size: 48pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: -50px;
}

.game {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  position: center;
  border: 14px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  background-color: black;
}

#player {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 470px;
  left: 400px;
}

#gun {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  top: -20px;
  left: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#bullet {
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkorange;
  width: 8px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 1px;
  animation: shoot 0.7s linear;
}

@keyframes shoot {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -470px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Galaxy Invaders</p>
<div class="game">
  <div id="player">
    <div id="gun">
      <div id="bullet"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="enemy"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements CSS property values acquired by `.style` aswell as per `getComputedStyle()` will be returned by Javascript as strings like `10px` for `div { left: 10px}`, containing unit types depending on the CSS property.

You will have to substract the unit types from those strings and then your `parseInt` should work:

```
parseInt(style.left.replace('px', ''))
```